# Running Visual Studio in Windows Safe Mode

Tags: visual-studio, window, safe-mode

I am trying to run Visual Studio in Windows safe mode as my laptop has developed some issues and runs only on Safe mode. Unfortunately while running a program, local host refuses to connect. I am not sure what is the problem. Please help

Comment: Check if you are in safe mode with networking. But remember, safe mode is meant to troubleshoot your device not to use it in production. I'm pretty sure that you will experience other issues even if you will be able to connect to localhost.

Comment: Thank you so much,in safe mode with networking.Just stuck with This laptop for few days due to covid with Total Lockdown